greenplum pxf server create external tabe based on parquet hdfs file with partition in select
I have a parquet hdfs file with partitions and I want to create external table in greenplum with partition columns in it.
This is HDFS file
CREATE TABLE productshelf.funnel (
    system_product_id STRING,
    system_channel_id STRING,
) PARTITIONED BY (
    rules_calc_dt BIGINT,
    segment_id BIGINT
) STORED AS PARQUET
TBLPROPERTIES ('PARQUET.COMPRESS'='SNAPPY', 'transactional'='false');

Below is my attempt to create external table via pxf server
create external table aaas.aggregates_ext (
                system_product_id text
                , system_channel_id text 
                , rules_calc_dt integer 
                , segment_id integer
)
LOCATION (
   'pxf://user/productshelf/hive/funnel/rules_calc_dt=*/segment_id=*?PROFILE=hdfs:parquet&SERVER="here is server name"'
) ON ALL
FORMAT 'CUSTOM' ( FORMATTER='pxfwritable_import' )
ENCODING 'UTF8';

But when I execute select * from aaas.aggregates_ext, below error has occured PXF server error: Column rules_calc_dt is missing from parquet schema
I understand, what does it mean, but i can't fix it. I try to change "PROFILE" parameter, but it doesn't work.
